# Why does the "geometry()" method work with a delay?

Tags: python, tkinter

If i run this Python code:

```
from Tkinter import *; w = Tk(); w.geometry( "640x480" ); print( w.geometry() )
```

i will get "1x1+0+0" output. But if i start interpreter and execute this as two separate 
commands, i will get completely different output:

```
>>> from Tkinter import *; w = Tk(); w.geometry( "640x480" ) 
'' 
>>> w.geometry() 
'640x480+101+73'
```

It seems geometry is not applied instantly, something else is needed : 
(. Maybe anyone knows what i need to do in order to update geometry 
inplace? I need it to correctly center/position main and child windows.

Comment: Good question.  I assume there is some delay time between creating the window, and reading its size.  Strangely, if I put a print "foo"; in between the last 2 statements it works, but if I put two of them python seems to hang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `update_idletasks()` on a window (or a widget) will force its geometry to update.

Here's a little text snippet from the Tkinter reference:

> The geometry is not accurate until the application has updated its idle tasks. In particular, all geometries are initially "1x1+0+0" until the widgets and the geometry manager have negotiated their positions.

Answer (score 0):

This completes, but gives wrong answer:

```
from Tkinter import *; w = Tk(); w.geometry( "640x480" ); print "foo"; print( w.geometry() )

''
foo
1x1+0+0
```

This seems to hang:

```
from Tkinter import *; w = Tk(); w.geometry( "640x480" );  print "foo"; print "foo"; print( w.geometry() )
```

Only a keyboard interrupt seems to get me out.

Sure enough, this does seem to work properly:

```
from Tkinter import *; w = Tk(); w.geometry( "640x480" ); w.update_idletasks(); print( w.geometry() )

''
640x480+5+27
```

Comment: Good point.  I just meant work in the sense that it ever completes.