# How to remove button in Tkinter while the function called on clicking it is still under execution?

Tags: python, tkinter

I used tkinter to create a button and assigned a function to it using `command` parameter. But this function contains some code takes time to execute. I have simulated it here using `time.sleep()`. I want to remove this button when this button is clicked. For this I called the global variable for button inside the function and then used `pack_forget()`.

```
from tkinter import *
import time


def signIn():
    global login_button
    login_button.pack_forget()
    # code after this takes some time to run.
    time.sleep(10)


login_screen = Tk()
login_button = Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=10, height=1, command=signIn)
login_button.pack()
login_screen.mainloop()
```

But the problem is that button gets removed only after the function execution is complete (i.e after 10 seconds). Is there any way I can get the button removed as soon as the `pack_forget()` line gets executed and not wait for the full function to complete execution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the "geometry()" method work with a delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934334/why-does-the-geometry-method-work-with-a-delay)

Comment: change `update_idletasks()` to `update()` could work.

Answer (score 2):

Call [update_idletasks](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) method of the *login_screen*  window after removing the button.

From *effbot*:

> **update_idletasks()**
>
> Calls all pending idle tasks, without processing any other events. This can be used to carry out geometry management and redraw widgets if necessary, without calling any callbacks.

```
def signIn():
    global login_button, login_screen
    login_button.pack_forget()
    login_screen.update_idletasks()
    # code after this takes some time to run.
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: nah, I tried this but it still it is taking 10 sec to remove the button.

Comment: @TarunKhare It is almost instantaneous for me. Could it be that the issue is somewhere else in your code? You might also want to checkout [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158811/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-update-idletasks).

Comment: I tried update() instead of update_idletasks() and it works!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in that situation.

```
def launch_button(*args):
    # button will show new text when this function is done. The second argument
    # is the new text we're sending to the button
    data_button_widget.configure(text=args[1])
    # schedule launch of the next function, 1 ms after returning to mainloop -
    # The first argument is the function to launch
    data_button_widget.after(1, args[0])


def get_data(*args):
    # button will reconfigure to original text when this function is done
    data_button_widget.configure(text='Original button text')
    <code that takes some time here>

# make a window
wndw = Tk()

# add a frame widget to the window
fram = ttk.Frame(wndw, padding=SM_PAD)
fram.grid(column=0, row=0)
wndw.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
wndw.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# make a button widget
data_button_widget = ttk.Button(fram, command=lambda: launch_button(get_data, 'wait...'))
data_button_widget.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=SM_PAD, pady=LG_PAD)
data_button_widget.configure(text='Original button text')

# start mainloop
wndw.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `update()` works:

```
def signIn():
    global login_button, login_screen
    login_button.pack_forget()
    login_screen.update()
    # code after this takes some time to run.
    time.sleep(10)
```